# a mod b, when b is greater than a

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Why

6 % 10 = 6

As fa as I know 10 % 6 = 4, but I don't know how to handle the first one

Thanks!

Comment: When you divide $6$ by $10$, you get quotient $0$ and remainder $6$

Comment: Hint: 6 = 0*10 + 6.

Comment: If you divide $6$ by $10$ what is the remainder?

Comment: the remainder is 0.6

Answer (score 1):

Division Theorem:

For any integer $M$ and any natural $n$ then if you divide $N$ by $n$ you will get a *unique* integer quotient $q$ and unique remainder integer $r$, between $0$ (inclusive) but less than $n$ so that $M= qn + r$.

$r$ is the remainder and $0 \le r < n$ and $q$ is the quotient and $q \le \frac Mn < q+1$.

And $M\% n = r$.  That is the definition.

SO if $M = 6$ and $n = 10$ what are $q$ and $r$ so that that:

$6 = q*10 +r$ and $q \le \frac{6}{1} < q+1$?

THe answers are:

$q=0$ and $r =6$.

$6 = 0*10 + 6$.

And so $6\% 10 =6$

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator a mod b gives the remainder when you divide a by b. Can you then work out the remainder when 6 is divided by 10?

Comment: Yes, the remainder is 0.6. (I guess, a practical way is just think on it as an integer).

Comment: When you take remainder you don’t consider decimals, only integers. Therefore 6=0*10+6 rather than 6=0.6*10+0.